# Dev tool Chrome error "DevTools failed to parse SourceMap"

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

Why am I getting the following from error message in the console:

> DevTools failed to parse SourceMap: chrome-extension://gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom/include.postload.js.map

I checked the dev tool settings and I have JS & Css enabled

Comment: The error message says it's an extension's script. You have an extension that doesn't include source maps. Report this issue to the extension author.

Answer (score 0):

If they are just unimportant warnings that are bothering you when leaving the console, you can temporarily disable them[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YIwq4.png)